# how do I use a blob instead of file and how do I adjust smartreadfile to use a blob instead of a path to a file?

Tags: php, mysql, audio, http-headers

So I have a website where I need to allow people to play some podcasts, and what we decided to do is store our mp3 files as longblobs in our mysql database at the portal that hosts our website.

What I'm looking for is how I stream my audio files to the player on the site. I can make a query to the database and fetch the data, which as far as I understand is returned in binary format(being a blob).

**What I've tried** :

- I used php to write the the data into a file and play that file, but the file is saved on our server which I want to avoid.
- Then I looked into tmp files but it seems I can't use the file as a source in the html src tag for audio.
- Then I tried encoding the binary data or the blob with base64 and placed it as a URI in the audio tag, but it took waaaay to long since the files are around 80-100mb in size.

Now I found a file called [**smartReadFile.php**](https://github.com/happyworm/smartReadFile) that streams a file with the accurate headers, but I don't really know much about headers so a link to something to help me understand that would be appreciated (maybe just a brief explanation).

But `smartReadFile` need a path to a mp3 file, and I dont have that and since I dont know anything about headers I'm really not sure how to edit the file as I need it to make a query to the database(I know how to do this much), and then use the returned data instead of a filepath to a mp3 file, and this what I would like some help to accomplish.
How can I use the blob to replace a path to a mp3 file?

This is my first question on here and it might be a bit vague so any help in any kind would be appreciated!

Comment: For what it's worth, your decision to use database blobs instead of a file-oriented content server is contrary to the way almost everybody handles this problem.  Why? Lots of reasons. Here are some. First, your MySQL server is your scarce resource. If your service gains lots of users, all content requests will use MySQL, so you won't be able to just add web servers. Second, client software (audio players) often use byte range requests to download files chunk by chunk. Web servers just work for this, but not php programs. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7233. I urge you to reconsider.

Comment: @O.Jones Thank you for answering, I chose to handle the problem the way I did for 2 reasons, one being [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2445/files-in-the-database-or-not) and the other being the reason that our web host once took down our website since we had stored all our files on the server (40+ files at 80-110mb) and they told us to move the files elsewhere, so we decided to use this solution.

Comment: @O.Jones 
I thought that I could use the 'SmartReadFile' to fetch the blob 'chunk by chunk' as you describe it and somehow use it as a the source for the html audio tag. Using 'URI' actually worked fine, but it just took too long to query the blob and den encode it with base64 and then use it as a URI, and thought it was the time encoding the blob with base64 that was taking so long. Is it not possible to use httpheaders to fetch the blob in chunks, encode them and use them as URI somehow?

Comment: Put your files on a content distribution network like Amazon S3 / Cloudfront.  Or, fire your hosting provider and get a better one. But don't cripple your service by trying to use database BLOBs for audio content.